# What is the difference between "could be" and "could well be"?

Tags: difference, indian-english

What is the difference between *could be* and *could well be* in this sentence I found at the bottom right side of page 4 on https://d2cyt36b7wnvt9.cloudfront.net/exams/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/12173028/hess306.pdf?

> Advocate Roy examines Sushil and his employer as defense witness. Through their testimonies, she was able to show that Rs 10,000 found in Shanti's trunk **could well be** the earnings of Sushil and Shanti.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The addition of *well* emphasises the likelihood of the statement being true; it changes *may be* to *probably is.*

https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/may-might-could-well

Comment: It's related to this question so I don't think it's worth of a new question. Is there a difference in meaning between .`..could/may/might well be...` and `...could/may/might as well be...`?

Comment: @ihavenoidea There is definitely a difference. I think this is worthy of its own question, honestly. The nuance there is very obvious to me (a native speaker) but I can see that it would be very confusing to a learner!

Comment: I don't agree that "could well be" suggests anywhere near the level of likelihood that "probably is" does. "Probably" indicates a probability significantly above 50%, whereas "could well" just indicates a probability significantly above 0%.

Comment: @ihavenoidea: They actually mean completely different things. "He might well be X" means "It's quite possible that he *is* X", whereas "He might as well be X" means "He *isn't* X, but it wouldn't make a difference if he *were*".